# Generated JAR file is not executing

Tags: java, jar, text-files, executable-jar

I have a java project which reads data from an the excel sheet (specified by the user), performs some filtering and creates a few text files and then writes the modified data to the text files.

The project is working fine and now I want to create a jar file for it. I created the jar file but it did not run. As far as the code is concerned it is running without any errors.I have used Netbeans for GUI. I also saw related questions which said it is not possible to create a text file from a running jar.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: *"But I am facing some problems with this."* What problems?  Copy/paste error or exception output as an edit into the question.  Please don't assume we can read your mind or see your IDE.

Comment: sorry for not specifying this.
I created the jar file but it did not run. 
The code is running without any errors.

Comment: There are no errors in the code. I am just looking for a way to run my program from an executable jar file.

Comment: *But I am facing some problems with this.*: which problems? Any exception stack trace? What should the program do and what does it do instead? When you go see your doctor, you don't just tell him: "I'm sick". You go into details. You describe the symptoms. Do the same here.

Comment: *"The code is running without any errors."* Are there any `catch` statements in the code?  Run it from the command line using something like `java -jar our.jar`

Comment: Just ran it from the command prompt.
There was a problem with finding the main class.
Because there were two classes with the main method. It worked after rectifying this problem.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the main class in the manifest of the jar file.

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the manifest, which has the general form:   Main-Class: classname

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html